# How to get ComputeIfPresent working with Map within Map?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

When trying to alter a Map using the **computeIfPresent()** method I have trouble implementing this method when I use an innerMap.

**This works:**

```
Map<String, Integer> mapOne = new HashMap<>();
mapOne.computeIfPresent(key, (k, v) -> v + 1);
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mapTwo = new HashMap<>();
mapTwo.computeIfPresent(key, (k, v) -> v.computeIfPresent(anotherKey, (x, y) -> y + 1);
```

In the second example  I get the following error message: "Bad return type in lambda expression: Integer cannot be converted to `Map<String, Integer>`". 
My IDE recognizes v as a Map. But the function doesn't work.

Apparently the method returns an Integer, but I fail to see how this differs from the first method with no Innermap. So far I haven't found a similar case online.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: in the first example the map is of the type `<String, Integer>` and hence the lambda function returning and integer is fine. However, in the second example, the map is of the type `<String, Map>` so the lambda function should return a map.. not an integer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The outer lambda expression should return the `Map` referenced by `v`:

```
mapTwo.computeIfPresent(key, 
                        (k, v) -> {
                                v.computeIfPresent(anotherKey, (x, y) -> y + 1); 
                                return v;
                            });
```

It cannot return the `Integer` value of the expression `v.computeIfPresent(anotherKey, (x, y) -> y + 1);`.

Answer (score 9):

In order to understand your problem lets take a look at the signature of the method you are using:

`V computeIfPresent(K key, BiFunction<? super K,? super V,? extends V> remappingFunction)`

As you can see, it returns a type based on the `V` generic parameter which stands for a value that is stored in `Map`. This is where you face the problem: your inner map stores `Integer`, so when you call `computeIfPresent`, you get `Integer` while your outer map requires another `Map`.

**EDIT:**
While writing, I realized that Eran gave a code example already which shows how to do it.
But I will leave this answer since it explains why your approach doesn't work, so it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off-topic (sort of), but doing the same thing for *the same* Map, breaks in mysterious ways:

```
// breaks with ConcurrentModificationException
Map<String, Integer> test = new HashMap<>(); // or  = new Hashtable<>();
test.computeIfAbsent("one", x -> test.computeIfAbsent("one", y -> 1));

// IllegalStateException: Recursive update
Map<String, Integer> test = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
// ... same code

// the only one that works correctly that I am aware of
Map<String, Integer> test = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
```